# Windows Server 2003: Router, DHCP, Loses internet connection

Tags: windows-server-2003, router, dhcp, isp

I have following setup: a windows server 2003 dedicated server with tho nics. One is connected to internet (no modem/router), and second one is connected to private network. Server has DHCP server installed on it and internet nic is being shared for internet access.

The problem is sometimes server loses connection to the internet, so same happens to private network. So far I can manually fix it by releasing and renewing IP address.

What could be the cause of this problem? DHCP lease from ISP?

Thanks

Comment: ...so, how are you exactly connecting a NIC to the Internet without a router?

Comment: Verizon Fios 25/25. They provide an ONT box and you can have ethernet connection from ONT box to your router/computer. Modem is necessary when using coax only in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't that box be (sort of) a router, then?

Comment: Well um, its fiber optic btw, and I think fiber optic with ONT boxes works kinda like a regular network would. Might be wrong.

Comment: Are all your IP addresses static? You may be having a problem with which route has the highest priority

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an intermittant router/modem fault, but you have to check your side of things through doing some swap-and-tell :-)

Swap cables/network/patch ports and as a last resort, swap the interface function on your windows server, to see if the fault is tied to a driver or NIC.